# Topic mapping when streaming from Kafka to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

When I transfer or stream two and three tables then I can easily map in Elasticsearch but can I map automatically map topics to index

I have streamed data from PostgreSQL to ES by mapping manually `topic.index.map=topic1:index1,topic2:index2`, etc.

Can I map automatically whatever topics send by producer then consumer consume in ES connector automatically?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understood, can you clarify if what you want is to stream data from PostgreSQL to ES using Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the topics map directly to an index of the same name.

If you want "better" control, you can use `RegexRouter` in a `transforms` property

To quote the docs

> `topic.index.map`
>
> This option is now deprecated. A future version may remove it completely. Please use single message transforms, such as `RegexRouter`, to map topic names to index names

If you cannot capture a single regex for each topic in the connector, then run more connectors with a different pattern